# Volume form for submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

I just learned about differential forms and I'm trying to relate these ideas to vector calculus.

Let me explain what I want to do in terms of a few examples.

If I have a graph $y=x^2$ as a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and I want to find its canonical volume form, then what I can do is find the normal vector at each point and then do a little "magic".

More precisely, let $g(x,y)=y-x^2$ then taking its gradient (or exterior derivative) we get:
$$ d(y-x^2) = dy - 2x \ dx $$
Now, this is almost the volume form, except we have to swap $x$ and $y$ with $1$-forms perpendicular to them, so:
$$ dx-2x\ dy $$
is a volume form on $y=x^2$. Similarly, for the $2$-sphere: $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
$$ d(x^2+y^2+z^2-1) = 2x\ dx + 2y \ dy + 2z\ dz $$
Choosing the $2$-forms that are "perpendicular" to each of $dx$, $dy$ and $dz$:
$$ 2x \ dy\wedge dz + 2y \ dz\wedge dx + 2z \ dx\wedge dy $$
So what am I actually doing here? I would like to know the underlying mechanism for this "magic" that I'm doing in terms of manifolds language: e.g. tangent bundles, $k$-forms, etc.

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3022515/how-why-does-the-contraction-of-standard-volume-form-give-the-canonical-form?rq=1

Comment: See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3128164/71348) for a slight generalization.